# R.Java not generated after actionbar style changes

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, r.java-file

I am working on designing the actionbar. I was trying to change the color of the main actionbar. I had written a style in style.xml. Untill then my project is working fine. After I declared my style in xml file R.Java committed suicide.
The following is the xml code I had written. I had tried all the solutions given in this site. None of them worked for me.

```
<resources> 
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">F757575</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Someone help me

Thank you :)

Comment: Check for errors in your resource file and re build your project

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839596/manually-generate-r-java?rq=1 maybe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your color is not declared properly.

Change

```
<item name="android:background">F757575</item>
```

to

```
<item name="android:background">#FF757575</item>
```